# ASP.NetCore.Component - InputText width - how to set

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a InputText field

```
   <InputText id="Zip" class="form-control"
                       @bind-Value="obj.Zip" />
```

How do you set the width of the InputText?  css? How?

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputtext?view=aspnetcore-3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the style attribute like below:

```
<InputText id="Zip" class="form-control" style="width: 60px;" @bind-Value="obj.Zip"/>
```